# how to authenticate Java Springboot Restful API

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to get google OAuth2.0 work with the java spring boot WebAPI , I am currently reference it from spring-security documentation

After adding the dependency to pom.xml , every request seems get protected

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the configuration.java as below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
        .anyRequest().authenticated()        
    )
    .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();            
    }
}
```

After adding all this part , all my API request still not accessible even with the correct bearer token I got from google OAuth pass during request as header for authentication, it always return 401 Unauthorized from the postman , would like to know what am I missing and cause the program denied all request ?

API Code as follow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testauth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> createTask() {
  
    String result = "Hellow World"; 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: i suggest you read up what `httpBasic` actually is as it has nothing to do with token authentication. And what do you think `anyRequest().authenticated()` means?

Comment: hi @Toerktumlare token is being pass within header so it shall not be block , it seems like something is missing and causes all request not able to authenticate , that why all request return 401

Comment: I think that what he's trying to say is that you have obviously no idea of what you are doing and should get some education about OAuth2 and Spring Security before attempting to write security configuration. You may start with the link in my answer and continue with the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html).

Comment: follow the guidance in @ch4mp's answer, you need to add considerably more configuration to use OAuth2.

Comment: Actually, OAuth2 resource servers and clients can be configured with [0 Java conf](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) (which is less). Properties can be enough in most cases, including in multi-tenant scenarios with CORS configuration and authorities (roles) mapping. Only choosing and configuring an authorization server with identity federation takes more than 5 minutes (learning OAuth2 does take more than 5 minutes too...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `http.httpBasic(withDefaults())`, you require requests to be authorized with a `Basic` authorization header. It is perfectly expected that requests with a `Bearer` authorization header are unauthorized (and I believe you configured Postman to send requests with a `Bearer` authorization containing an access token from Google).

In OAuth2 requests authorization is made from either

- a `Bearer` authorization header (OAuth2 resource servers, with configuration eased by `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`)
- session (OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`, with configuration eased by `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`)

A REST API is usually configured as a resource server (requests authorized with an access token, like you are probably trying to do), not as a client (requests authorized with sessions, not access tokens).

The bad news is that Google authorization server is designed to be used with Google resource servers (Google APIs), not yours. You can hack around that (use `userinfo` endpoint as an introspection endpoint), but at the price of very bad performance.

If you want to make things properly, you should setup an authorization server of your own which would federate Google identities. There are plenty of options on the market with this kind of "login with Google" feature, either "on premise" (Keycloak is a famous sample) or in the cloud (Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, etc.). You could also build your own with `spring-authorization-server` but this is much more work (and requires quite some knowledge about web security in general and OAuth2 & OIDC in particular).

For more OAuth2 background and Spring Security configuration for  OAuth2, refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) and [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your guide , but now I am facing a new issue that I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963382/springboot-google-oauth2-0-decode-jwt-error-for-restapi , about the decoding JWT error . Do you have any tutorial similar for this ?

Comment: You should read answers more carefuly. I wrote above that you can't use Google tokens in your resource server. Just don't try. Setup an authorization server of your own as instructed. Google does not issue JWT access tokens. It issues opaque access tokens and does not expose an introspection endpoint (and even if it did, contacting a Google server at the beginning of each of the request your resource server processes would be way to expensive).