# Springboot Google OAuth2.0 decode JWT error for restAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting the following error for all request that required authenticate

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid unsecured/JWS/JWE header: Invalid JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

My Security configuration as below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{

//https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
private String jwkSetUri;

 @Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authen -> authen
                            .requestMatchers("/noauth")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)                
            .build();
    }

  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).jwsAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256).build();
  }
}
```

How can I make decode the jwt properly and allow my request as a valid request

Comment: why not just look at what response you are getting?

Answer (score -1):

Google tokens are to be used by your clients, only to call Google resource servers (Google APIs), not your own resource servers.

What you got from Google is an "opaque" access token, not a [**J**SON **W**eb **T**oken](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519).

Only JWTs can be decoded with a JWT decoder. Tokens in other formats must be introspected for validation: for each request, submit the token to the authorization server introspection endpoint, which surely adds latency and isn't acceptable when the Authorization server is located in another data-center or when the traffic grows.

Google does not expose an introspection endpoint. You could hack an introspector using the userinfo endpoint, but again, the performance cost is not acceptable.

To authenticate users with Google or other social providers, **setup your own authorization server and federate social identities**.

Keycloak is a famous sample of such an authorization server with identity federation. It is open-source and you can easily install it on your desktop and servers "for free" (will cost some time and computer resources). There are also many OpenID Providers in the cloud. This would save you most of the hassle of support (monitoring, updates, etc.). Auth0, Okta and Amazon Cognito are just samples, all emitting JWT access tokens and all proposing identity federation.

You might refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) for more details: it contains a README to help you configure some common authorization servers and tutorials for configuring Spring applications to use it.